# When does algorithms for manipulating random access lists is applied?

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, synchronize

In RandomAccess marker interface description it is written :

```
 * <p>The best algorithms for manipulating random access lists (such as
 * <tt>ArrayList</tt>) can produce quadratic behavior when applied to
 * sequential access lists (such as <tt>LinkedList</tt>).  Generic list
 * algorithms are encouraged to check whether the given list is an
 * <tt>instanceof</tt> this interface before applying an algorithm that would
 * provide poor performance if it were applied to a sequential access list,
 * and to alter their behavior if necessary to guarantee acceptable
 * performance.
```

In collection class synchronisedList method there is a check for RandomAccess & if success create SynchronizedRandomAccessList object but their also no details regarding algorithm.

```
public static <T> List<T> synchronizedList(List<T> list) {
    return (list instanceof RandomAccess ?
                new SynchronizedRandomAccessList<T>(list) :
                new SynchronizedList<T>(list));
    }
```

When does this algorithm apply and where(is it a native code) ?

Comment: `synchronizedList` creates a data-structure, it's not really an algorithm...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth that's right but see the docs comment,talking about algorithm... i m asking when & where the algorithm is applied

Comment: What algorithm are you referring to?

Comment: [RandomAccess](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/RandomAccess.java#RandomAccess) is used to check whether members of [Collections framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) are implementing it, so that Libraries like [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) having the algorithms can reap the performance benefits during Random Access in Sequential DataStructures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the examples is `Collections.binarySearch`:

```
public static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key) {
    if (list instanceof RandomAccess || list.size()<BINARYSEARCH_THRESHOLD)
        return Collections.indexedBinarySearch(list, key);
    else
        return Collections.iteratorBinarySearch(list, key);
}
```

Here different binary search algorithm implementations are used for random access and sequential access lists. Code is an implementation detail, but it's reasonable to differentiate lists here.

As specified in [documenation for Collections.binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29):

> This method runs in log(n) time for a "random access" list (which provides near-constant-time positional access). If the specified list does not implement the RandomAccess interface and is large, this method will do an iterator-based binary search that performs O(n) link traversals and O(log n) element comparisons.